# mysql nested query where in and in

Tags: mysql, nested

Trying to do a select in query within another one (potentially many more possible as a method of search of something that has all these characteristics but not sure about the syntax. Would like to do something like this:

```
Select person_name 
from people 
where person_name in (select person_name 
                      from people 
                      where characteristic ='tall') and 
      in (select person_name 
                 from people 
                 where characteristic ='thin')
```

(to find all the people's names who are tall and thin at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to get the persons having both characteristics:

```
select person_name 
from people 
where characteristic IN ('tall', 'thin')
group by person_name
having count(distinct characteristic) = 2
```

Then join to this subquery to get the rest of the fields:

```
select t1.*
from people t1
join (
   select person_name 
   from people 
   where characteristic IN ('tall', 'thin')
   group by person_name
   having count(distinct characteristic) = 2
) t2 on t1.person_name = t2.person_name
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find all the people's names who are tall and thin at the same time, I think you just need this query:

```
select person_name from people where characteristic in ('tall','thin')
```

just set the **characteristic** `in ('tall','thin')`